# Redirecting To Controller Actions with POST method in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-controller

I have an action named destroy in UserController I don't wanna work this action instead of UserInfoController@destroy supposed to run. So I need to redirect to the `UserInfoControlle@destroy` controller.

**UserController@destroy action;**

```
return redirect()->action(
                    'UserInfoController@destroy',['id' => 1]
                );
```

**Action successfully ran but I get this error;**

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Comment: redirects cause `get` requests

Comment: Please show your route implementation

Comment: @ml59
`Route::post('/delete/{id}''UserInfoController@destroy')->name('delete');`

Comment: @lagbox
So may I use get for `UserInfoController@destroy` route?

Comment: Yes, if you want to redirect. The browser cannot redirect to `post` route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some way to do that like below:

1. make new `get` route for that

   ```
   Route::get('/delete/{id}','UserInfoController@destroy')->name('deleteWithGetMethod');
   ```
2. change `post` to `any` in your route

   ```
   Route::any('/delete/{id}','UserInfoController@destroy')->name('delete');
   ```
3. return a view that contains below code

   ```
   <form id="myForm" action="{{ route('delete',$userInfoId) }}" method="post">
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
   </script>
   ```

Comment: looks this is the best solution, for now, I'll use `any` in my route.
Thank you.